# MDX - sum costs up to a given date

Tags: mdx, data-warehouse

This is a slight modification of what I stumbled upon while searching the web:
Let's say I have a dimension `PROJECTS` which contains:

> project_id - unique id
>
> category - category of a cost
>
> project_date - date of summing up the cost

My warehouse also has the dimension of `TIME` with date, and a dimension `COSTS` containing values of costs. Those three dimensions are connected by the measure group `EXPENSES` which has:

> id_date
>
> id_cost
>
> id_project

I want to wirte an MDX query which would group the projects by their category, and sum up all the costs, but **only those which do not exceed the date given in the project_date attribute of the dimension `PROJECTS`** (each category has the same project_date, I know it's redundant but I can't change it..)

Comment: you want to compare `project_date` to another date to make sure it has not exceeded it .... but what is the other date it needs to be compared to?

Comment: please can you include your current attempt Simon - even if it just shows us what is on rows and columns it helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but maybe something alongside this?

```
SELECT
[COSTS].[COST] ON 0,
[PROJECTS].[category] ON 1
FROM [CUBE]
WHERE
[PROJECTS].[project_date] < @project_date
```

Comment: The expenses is  a measure group so I cant select it. Did you mean 'projects'?  Besides, the NOW() function is not needed, because I have the time required in the project_date parameter

Comment: I am not sure that does the "@" mean. Also, shouldn't there be a `.currentmember.membervalue` or sth like that?

Comment: the @project_date is your reporting parameter. No idea about the currentmember :-)

Comment: There is no such thing as project_date parameter - that's the result

Comment: Please, adjust your question then.. 'only those which do not exceed the date given in the parameter project_date'. You clearly state you want a parameter `project_date`.

Comment: Changed it - didnt even know parameters existed in MDX .. Now it should be clear,sorry!

Comment: @Gudgip why do you include a parameter? Are you assuming that simon is using `SSRS`? He has not included that tag.

Comment: @Gudgip you have the dimension `[PROJECTS]` on two axes which is not valid `mdx`.

Comment: @whytheq he asked for a parameter before, he editted his question though :-)